# implementing a custom layer to generate 2d exponential images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I need to implement a custom layer (in Tensorflow or Keras), which generates 2d gaussian heatmaps with learnable parameters (variance). I want this layer to take the center for each sample - which is the ground truth landmark coordinates- as input and output 2d gaussian images for them.
However, I'm not sure how I can implement it as I have to iterate through the number of samples, which is not possible during compilation in the 'call' method when the number of samples is 'None'.
More specifically, in case there is only one sample, this is how I generate the heatmaps:

```
def call(self,landmark):

    x, y = tf.meshgrid(tf.linspace(-100.0,100.0,128), tf.linspace(-100.0,100.0,128))
    d = tf.sqrt((x-landmark[0])**2+(y-landmark[1])**2)

    g=tf.exp(-tf.square(d)/(2*self.sigma**2))/(2*np.pi*self.sigma)
    return g
```

However, assuming landmarks are input tensors having a shape of (None,2) initially, how can I implement a layer which outputs a corresponding result for each of those samples?

Answer (score 0):

One answer I came up with, I'm not sure how well it works:
You can make a list of the 2d constant mesh images and landmarks and pass them as an input at the same time, then the call function would be:

```
def call(self, x):
    image, landmark = x
    sub = image - landmark

    sigma = self.kernel

    d = KB.sqrt((sub[:, :, :, 0]) ** 2 + (sub[:, :, :, 1]) ** 2)

    g = tf.exp(-tf.square(d) / (2 * sigma ** 2)) / (2 * np.pi * sigma)

    return g
```